# AWS Fargate modify /etc/hosts on startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am calling an external API and the only way to call is when I have a hosts file entry. So right now I ECS Exec and add it there. I want to automate it so when I autoscale I don't have to ECS Exec to add the hosts file entry on each task.

Below is part of my task definition that has Entrypoint / command. They both are empty. I believe I can use one of them to do this but not 100% sure.

```
  "entryPoint": null,
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "hostPort": 8000,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "containerPort": 8000
    }
  ],
  "command": null,
```

Comment: Can you set up a DNS record in Route 53 instead?

Comment: Look into Route53 private hosted zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for the sake of others with similar needs. There's 3 ways to  make this work.

1. Like the commentors have pointed out R53 private hosted zones (costs money + affects the entire VPC, not just your containers)
2. Create a Startup.sh which can have logic to add to hosts and add it as part of your container deployable and invoke it using the DockerFile

   ADD RunStartUp.sh RunStartUp.sh
   CMD["./RunStartUp.sh"]
3. Directly add the hosts entry using entryPoint/Command in the task definition json

   "entryPoint": [
   "sh",
   "-c"
   ],
   "command" : [
   "/bin/sh -c "echo '122.123.423.12 google.com >> \etc\hosts ""
   ]